# How to split comma delimited values into multiple rows using Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using Python and `SQLite` to manipulate a string in android. 
I have a `SQLite` Table that looks like this:

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA, Germany, Mexico 
| 2              | Brazil, Canada
| 3              | Peru
```

I would like to split the comma delimited values of Country column and insert them into another table countries so that Countries table looks like this

```
| ID             | Country     
+----------------+-------------
| 1              | USA
| 1              | Germany
| 1              | Mexico
| 2              | Brazil
| 2              | Canada
| 3              | Peru
```

How do I do split the values from Country column in one table and insert them into Country column of another table?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [recursive common table expression](https://sqlite.org/lang_with.html) to split the comma-delimited column by extracting substrings of the Country column recursively.

```
CREATE TABLE country_split AS
WITH RECURSIVE split(id, value, rest) AS (
   SELECT ID, '', Country||',' FROM country
   UNION ALL SELECT
   id,
   substr(rest, 0, instr(rest, ',')),
   substr(rest, instr(rest, ',')+1)
   FROM split WHERE rest!=''
)
SELECT id, value
FROM split
WHERE value!='';
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `split` function in SQLite.  
There is of course the `substring` function but it's not suitable for your needs since every row could contain more than 1 commas.  
If you were an expert in SQLite I guess you could create a recursive statement using `substring` to split each row.  
If you're not use Python to read the data, split each row and write it back to the db.

Answer (score 0):

im solved
im using python

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
db = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""Select * from Countries""")
all_data = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Countriess
                    (ID TEXT,
                    Country TEXT)""")
for single_data in all_data:
    countriess  = single_data[1].split(",")
    for single_country in countriess :
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Countriess VALUES(:id,:name)", { "id": single_data[0], "name": single_country })
db.commit()
```

and after use sqlite db another project;  :)